# Calculating population density per sq km in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I'm using QGIS 2.10 and I have a table with the following data:

[image]

Where `"ALAND10"` is the area in square meters and `"DP0010001"` is the total population.

How to calculate population density per 1sq km? I have ~30 000 entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a new field where you define the following formula:

```
"DP0010001"/("ALAND10"/1000000)
```

It should return the density per square meter.

As a reference, follow the instructions in the following image:

[image]